# redis-server - Command Not Found

Tags: node.js, redis

Totally new to nodejs and redis. Node.js is working fine and NPM works fine too.

I want to play around with Redis so I ran:

```
npm install redis
```

and this seemed to work ok but now I'm trying to run:

```
redis-server
```

and I'm getting a **Command Not Found** error.
I'm on a Mac if that's relevant.

Can anyone offer some advice?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`npm install redis` doesn't install redis, it installs a redis *client* for node. You need to install the redis server.

Answer (score 19):

I downloaded `http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz`

```
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make
```

I added this line to my `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Downloads/redis-stable/src
```

restarted the terminal. Now can run `redis-server`

Comment: I think this is the solution.

Comment: Excuse me, what is the .bash_profile in Windows?

Comment: @Ivan you might wanna search about Environment Variables

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the command `redis-server` can use directly.
If you install Redis before , find the path where your Redis install.
eg :
/home/prod/redis/redis-4.0.8/src/redis-server
Then
you can command this in terminal :

```
 ln -s /home/prod/redis/redis-4.0.8/src/redis-server /usr/bin/redis-server2
```

Note: path "/usr/bin" is your environment path .

cd /usr/bin
ls -ltr
you can see :

```
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root         45 7月  12 11:05 redis-server -> /home/prod/redis/redis-4.0.8/src/redis-server
```

Now the command of `redis-server` can be used

Answer (score 2):

npm install redis doesn't install redis, it installs a redis client for node. You need to install the redis server

**On Windows:**

I downloaded http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz

tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make

I added this line to my .bash_profile:

export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Downloads/redis-stable/src

restarted the terminal. Now can run redis-server

**On Mac:**

brew install redis

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is above but also this worked for me

1. Download this `http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz` (just paste the link on Opera)
2. Open a terminal and cd to the folder that has the files (mostly it's in downloads folders) and try something like this

   ```
   tar xvzf file.tar.gz
   cd redis-stable
   make
   ```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question of OG.